# How to resolve memory issue while scaling / roating a bitmap in android?

Tags: android

I want to zoom and roate a image in an Android activity. 
I am doing it as follows

```
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        matrix.postScale(zoomScale,zoomScale);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

but it gives me a memory error after a few rotations and zooming.
How can i resolve this ? Most application do it pretty efficiently on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is resolved by finding the width and height of the image first by the inJustDecodeBounds option. Then, use the values to find and set the inSampleSize to load a scaled image. Please refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for detail.

Comment: In the future, it's a good idea to add the referenced code right to your answer in case your link disappears.  :)